# Angular v15 directives not working as in v14

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular2-directives

In angular 14 the selector was "working" and the second < input > was the only one affected by the directive. In Angular v15 the directive is not working so i added the "standalone: true" and the "hostDirectives". But now, the directive is working in both < input > not only in the one that matches the selector

directive

```js
yearFormat = ...

@Directive({
  standalone: true, //this is new
  selector: '[myDirective]',
  providers: [{ provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: yearFormat }]

})
export class CustomDateFormatDirective {}
```

Component

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-datepicker-field',
  template: `
     <input>no directive</input>
     <input myDirective>with directive</input>
    `,
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  hostDirectives:[CustomDateFormatsDirective] //This is new
})
export class myDatePickerCompent{}
```

How can i make it work as before?

Answer (score 0):

by adding `hostDirectives:[CustomDateFormatsDirective]` you are assigning a directive to the `app-datepicker-field` element. and, as a result both inputs are affected by `MAT_DATE_FORMATS`. remove hostDirectives and it should be resolved

Comment: If i remove `hostDirectives:[CustomDateFormatsDirective]` then the directive never gets instantiated

Comment: did you add the directive into the module where myDatePickerCompent is declated?

Comment: I think you should remove `standalone: true` from the directive and add it to the module `declarations`

Comment: yes @Andrei, removing `hostDirectives[]`, `standalone`, and declaring the directive in the module the directive works in angular v14 but not in v15 (it never get instantiated). That's the reason y convert it to `hostDirective`. It is like the selector is never used.

Comment: could you try `[myDirective]=""` instead of just `myDirective`